# DNS resolve sometimes connection timed out

Tags: linux, dns, bind

Good day to all. Made a command: nslookup kafka.zxc.stage @dns1.prod And sometimes I get an answer - ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

For example, when I run a command every second, 6 requests in 6 seconds. Part of the answers "no servers could be reached".

I thought this was strange. And I decided to look using the tcpdump utility. I will give two examples. When nslookup returned A record and when "no servers could be reached".

Everything is fine. The response was returned to the console -

```
3926 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40303, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 202) 
dns-int.prod > kafka.zxc.stage.33173: [bad udp cksum 0x4e30 -> 0x6909!] 14677* q: A? kafka.stage. 2/2/2 kafka.stage. [10m] CNAME kafka.zxc.stage., kafka.zxc.stage. [10m] A 100.200.40.22 ns: stage.zone. [30m] NS dns2-int.prod., stage.zone. [30m] NS dns-int.prod . ar: dns-int.prod . [1h] A 100.100.100.200, dns2-int.prod. [30m] A 100.100.100.100 (174)
```

Send next request, about 2-3 seconds of waiting, the console returns ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached" -

```
4662 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40543, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 129) 
dns-int.prod > kafka.zxc.stage.52157: [bad udp cksum 0x4de7 -> 0x6fe7!] 53* q: AAAA? kafka.zxc.stage. 0/1/0 ns: stage.zone. [4d] SOA dns1.prod. admindn.mail.(101)
```

As I understand it, A record is for IPv4, but AAAA record for IPv6.

I still don’t understand why he is trying to send requests this way. I would be very glad if someone could point me in the direction of finding a solution. I will also look for a solution. Thanks.

All this, if i send nslookup nonstop requests to dns1,
dns2 (slave) don't have a errors.

Example nslookup to dns1 -

```
 # nslookup kafka.zxc.stage 100.100.100.100
Server:     100.100.100.100
Address:    100.100.100.100#53

kafka.zxc.stage canonical name = kafka.stage.
Name:   kafka.zxc.stage
Address: 100.200.40.22
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Send answer, but connection timed out?
OR

```
# nslookup kafka.zxc.stage 100.100.100.100
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

This is floating problem.

Time to answer too long, i was check it

```
for i in {0..5}; do time dig @100.100.100.100 +short kafka.zxc.stage ; done 2>&1 | grep real
real    0m5.018s
real    0m5.012s
real    0m0.016s
real    0m0.013s
real    0m5.015s
real    0m10.021s
```

the named configuration has not changed.
But the OS configuration changed.
I'm checking further

Comment: Yes A is for v4 and AAAA for v6 and nslookup by default looks up _both_; see the section of the man page for the setting/option of `querytype/type`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The problem then lies elsewhere. Long time answer I guess.
Edited the question and added comments below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error on Virtual IP, he is not listen, but work.
After recreate new line at netstat -

```
tcp        0      0 100.100.100.100:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29671/named
```

Recreate it and all ok.